# SharePoint 2013 Column Filters do not show up in Quick Edit

Tags: 2013, quick-edit

Most times the filters do not show up in quick edit view; occasionally they do and everything works as expected.  The list has under 1000 items and is far under the throttle limits.  What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Never found an answer to this one...

Comment: It might be a browser issue. Try with a different browser.

Comment: It didn't work at all from some browsers and was intermittent in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an hold issue but you could also check to use http instead of https (and viceversa). It depends of your binding configuration on SharePoint.

Hope it helps someone.